# SQL - Pivot rows to columns and take cartesian product

Tags: sql, join, pivot, cross-join

I'm trying to do the following using only SQL queries. I'm not quite sure how, but think I should be using pivot and maybe a cross join?

Transform the first table, call it `entries`, to the second table `combined`

`entries`:

```
study_id     participant    condition_1    condition_2   condition_3

   1          user_1          true            false        false

   1          user_2          true            true         false

   2          user_2          false           false        true
```

`combined`:

```
study_id  user_1condition_1  user_1condition_2  user_1condition_3  user_2condition_1  user_2condition_2 user_2condition_3

   1            true               false              false              true                true               false

   2            N/A                N/A                N/A                false               false              true
```

We can see this is essentially populating a table with fields that are the cartesian product of the participants with the conditions. But I'm not sure how to make the new table and populate it with SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for group by along with MAX logic to get you the results you want.

```
select study_id
       ,max(case when participant='user_1' then condition_1 end) as user_1condition_1
       ,max(case when participant='user_1' then condition_2 end) as user_1condition_2
       ,max(case when participant='user_1' then condition_3 end) as user_1condition_3
from entities
group by study_id
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain this query a bit more? Also I'm assuming the expressions need to be repeated for user 2?

Comment: Yes, for the other users you can use the same pattern of MAX(<expression>). In the expected result we have study_id which is non-repeating, and therefore i group by study_id. After that i am selectively getting the value for condition if the particpant is 'user_1' which gets me the user_1condition_1, and then i repeat this for condition_2,_3 etc